# jaged edges and text in inkscape design, print on demand

Tags: inkscape, anti-aliasing

I am stuck into a problem several days, i can't figure out how to get clean edges, even if i used a high resolution 600 dpi (when exporting to png) but the edges seems jagged when i view the design in print on demand website.

i drew the line art in inkscape version 0.92.3 with bezier tool
this is the link : there are jaggies in the beard of marcus aurelius design
[the image in the previewer of teespring](https://teespring.com/fr/be-stoic-marcus-aurelius-2020?pid=1096&cid=104158)

I tried to export as pdf but i can't remove the background from the pdf (and teespring don't accept pdf),

how can the others have good clean edges in their design ?

Edit: there is another design i tried with simple text that i drew with bezier but i have the same problem[image]

and it's look like that in the previwer [jagged text](https://teespring.com/fr/amor-fati-apatheia-andreia?pid=389&cid=100019)

and here is the link with new png with size 9000 * 10800px [enter link description here](https://teespring.com/fr/amor-fati-apatheia-andreia-2?pid=373&cid=100034)

Comment: Did you make your vector artwork the actual finished size you wanted it ? Or did you enlarge it after it was exported as a .png ? It looks like a raster image which was enlarged.

Comment: i did my vector artwork the actual finished size with 300 dpi and i also tried with 600 dpi but the result is the same

Comment: How can you tell? That site creates a unified PNG of your artwork with the garment.. i.e. it generates a *new* png... not the one you upload. Contact the site for guidance. PNG have pixels... they will *always* be there to some degree, especially on angles and curves.

Comment: but when i browse the products of other designers, it looks good, so if it isn't the same png how the products of the others looks good? in the tips of their site they tell to turn off the anti-aliasing to have good edges, i tried several solutions in the internet to turn off the antialiasing in inkscape but the result is the same, even it don't seem correct to turn off anti aliasing, i contacted the teespring but they didn't give me a solution (just reading the tips on the site) they explain how to turn off anti aliasing in illustrator but not on inkscape

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. To say that an image is 600dpi or 300dpi is basically meaningless.  A small 600dpi image will look like crap if you print it big.  You will see the pixels. DPI is not a measure of quality. You need to provide more information here. What size is it going to be printed at in physical dimensions (inches/cm)?  What size is the PNG in pixels?

Comment: Chances are any "sample" images the site uses as promotion are *carefully* recreated to be higher quality than the online "building preview".

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank you, I think the size in physical dimensions is 12.40" x 14.88" because when i hover the design while uploading it the previewer displays those dimensions, the size of the png is 4500 * 5400 px, i have tried to export a new png with 600 dpi and the size of the new png is 9000 * 10800 px i will put the link of the uploaded image in the website, the jaggies always remain

Comment: @Scott I don't know but i hope that they recreated it in higher quality

Comment: An image 12.4" x 14.88" at 600ppi should be 7440px x 8928px.  The pixelization you are seeing might  have something to do with the way the website is building the preview, and probably has nothing to do with your actual image.  I think you really need to contact those who run the site to find out why this is happening. Perhaps it has something to do with the colour mode but that's only a guess. Sorry, that's about as much as I can really help you with.

Comment: If it's any consolation, the image you posted looks absolutely fine at 100% zoom. There is no pixelization, so the fault lies elsewhere.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you very much for your explanation and help ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This case stays unsolvable here. Teespring's previews are low resolution images, only 480 x 480 pixels. The actual printed shape is there less than 200 px high. They cannot show things right if you try to zoom the full preview bigger than actual 480 x 480 pixels on the screen. If your screen is 1200 pixels high the preview can be reliably watched only as small as 40% of the screen height.

If you suspect the actual print has also low resolution ask Teespring support. We cannot check it, they show details only for registered customers. If they do not plausibly confirm (for whatever reason) the actual print resolution is high enough for you go elsewhere.

Comment: I contacted them 3 days ago and  they respond me by " You can view some great tips and recommendations in this link https://community.teespring.com/training-center/design-file-tips-best-practices/ ", thank you for your help, i think it's the website problem